# Insert a REST in the OTP to invoke the SendMail service

Tags: java, spring, microservices

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/createOtp")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto<OTPDto>> createOtp(@Valid @RequestBody OTPDto otpDto, String username) { //throws Exception
                                                                               
   log.info("INIZIO getOTP - registerUserDto: {}", otpDto);
   OTPDto response = otpFacade.createOTP(otpDto,username);
   log.info("FINE getOTP - response: {}", response);

   return ResponseEntity.ok(ResponseDto.<OTPDto>builder().noinfo(response).build());
}
```

```
@PostMapping(value = "/sendMailNoAttachment")
public String sendMailNoAttachment(@RequestBody MailObj mailObj) throws IOException {
    log.info("INIZIO sendMailNoAttachment");
    emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mailObj.getEmailAddress(), mailObj.getSubject(), mailObj.getText());
    log.info("FINE sendMailNoAttachment");

    return "Your mail has been send to the user.";
}
```

The two controllers, in two different foulders how do I call the method and insert in SendMail??
Thank you
it won't let me insert the two complete controllers

Comment: what is the desired outcome? remember that we don't know what each method does (createOTP, sendSimpleMessage) so you need to tell us what you want to happen.

Comment: Sorry you're right createOTP creates a random OTP, while sendSimpleMessage sends a simple email with from(prefix),to,subject and text @
Tom Elias

Comment: okay, but what do you want to do? it is not clear from the question. what is the trigger to the operation and what is the desired outcome?

Comment: practically I have these two microservices in two separate packages and I have to insert the sendEmail in the OTP with a REST call @ 
Tom Elias

Comment: we don't know your code and we can't know what "insert sendEmail in the OTP" mean. maybe its a language issue. your question isn't clear. i'm *guessing* you need to Autowire the "otp facade" in your email controller and call "createOtp" before "sendSimpleMessage". we can't help you with the business logic of your application.